# Time complexity in terms of n if time complexity is O(x*y) where x+y = n

Tags: arrays, time-complexity

This code is to move all the zeroes in the vector to the end of the vector while maintaining the order of the non zero elements.

Eg: 0 3 0 8 0 9

Output : 3 8 9 0 0 0

I wrote the following code for this

```
void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<int> v, v1; // v has the index of all the zero elements while v1 has index of non zero elements
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
        if(nums[i] == 0)
            v.push_back(i);
        else v1.push_back(i);
    }
    //Here i'm swapping all the zero elements with non zero elements
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < v1.size(); j++){
            if(v[i] < v1[j]){
            swap(nums[v[i]], nums[v1[j]]);
            v[i] = v1[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if nums has size n and v has size x & v1 has size y where `x + y = n`, then time complexity is O(x*y) . But what will be the time complexity in terms of n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `N` be the the number of elements in the vector.
In the **best case** the time complexity would be linear, i.e, `O(N)`. This happens in 2 cases:

- when all the elements are non-zero. The second loop in which you swap elements would not be executed (v would be empty)
- when all the elements are zero. In such a case only the first part of the second loop would run (v1 would be empty).

In the other cases you incur in a quadratic time complexity `O(N^2)` due to the double loop.
For instance, suppose that half of the elements are zero and the other half is non-zero. This means that the number of iterations would be.

```
N/2*N/2 = N^2/4 = O(N^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> So if nums has size n and v has size x & v1 has size y where x + y = n, then time complexity is O(x*y) . But what will be the time complexity in terms of n?

Could be up to O(n<sup>2</sup>) if `x` and `y` are roughly `n/2`, e.g: `y = x = n / 2 => x * y = n^2/4`.

I recommend you to do the following:

```cpp
void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums)
{
    for(int i = 0, p = 0; i < (int)nums.size(); ++i)
        if(nums[i])
        {
            if(p != i)
                swap(nums[i], nums[p]);
            ++p;
        }
}
```

Pointer `p` indicates how many non zero elements have been swapped.

This way you get an O(n) time complexity, the code is clearer and don't use an extra O(n) memory consumption.